# ¿Cómo manejar un ItemListener solo cuando se confirme la selección en un JComboBox?

Tags: java, eventos

Tengo un `jComboBox` no editable donde quiero que se ejecute una acción cuando se cambie de item pero `ItemStateChange()` se dispara al hacer una búsqueda de contenido, es decir, que se coloca en el item que empieza con la letra que se teclea y lo que quiero es que `ItemStateChange()` se ejecute cuando ya se haya confirmado el item (cuando el popup del `jComboBox` se cierra).

¿Cómo hago para saber cuando el usuario confirma la selección con un enter o con un clic?

Comment: ¿Qué es `ItemStateChange()`? No es una método ni un listener de `JComboBox`

Comment: Es un método de `ItemListener` que se ejecuta cuando un item es seleccionado o deseleccionado.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939/jcombobox-selection-change-listener

Answer (score 0):

Luego de estar intentando, lo que se me ocurrió fue usar `popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible()` de `PopupListener` para que la acción se ejecute cuando el `JComboBox` se cierre.